# How to customize logback.xml file

Tags: java

I want to customize my logback.xml file for 3 levels (error,debug,info)  .I do like this  :

```
<configuration> 

    <appender name="FILE-ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logs/ApplicationLogs.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
    <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-DEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logs/ApplicationLogs.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
    <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-INFO" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logs/ApplicationLogs.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
    <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    </appender>



    <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
    </root>

    <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-DEBUG" />
    </root>

    <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INFO" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

But I didn't get the correct loges information  .Do logback.xml in wrong format?

Comment: You cannot declare root logger with different levels. You should use filters in the appenders. And you'll have to configure different files. or they go in one file again and all your filtering would be nonsense.

Comment: also : you're logging to the same file in each appender ... which doesnt make any sense, a single appender would do exactly the same .. basically, you're just wasting resources

Comment: Have a look at this: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html . Search for "LevelFilter" and "ThresholdFilter". There are also examples.

Comment: Oh, wait. Did you want to just log ERROR,INFO and DEBUG into one file? Then forget all the above advice. Keep one appender, add it to **the** root logger which you set to "DEBUG". This will automatically log ERROR, INFO and DEBUG, because DEBUG is the lowest Level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to log the Levels ERROR, INFO and DEBUG to one file.
Please change your config as so:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
<file>logs/ApplicationLogs.log</file>
<encoder>
<pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
<appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Logback will then log all events of levels DEBUG and higher. That means it will log DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR.
You can leave out `<append>true</append>` it is the default.